# Desplegar(collapse) al presionar la fila de una tabla

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Al precionar una fila perteneciente a una tabla, este pueda desplegar con los datos que le corresponde.

solo debe mostrar el nombre del Pais, cuando presione al pais debe desplegar la informacion que le pertenese.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.List_Data = [{
      "idPais": 2,
      "Pais": "Bolivia",
      "idUnidad": 6,
      "idPais": 2,
      "Nombre": "Cochabamba"
    },
    {
      "idPais": 2,
      "Pais": "Bolivia",
      "idUnidad": 7,
      "idPais": 2,
      "Nombre": "Santa Cruz"
    },
    {
      "idPais": 2,
      "Pais": "Bolivia",
      "idUnidad": 8,
      "idPais": 2,
      "Nombre": "La Paz"
    },


    {
      "idPais": 3,
      "Pais": "Peru",
      "idUnidad": 5,
      "idPais": 3,
      "Nombre": "Cusco"
    },
    {
      "idEntidad": 1,
      "Pais": "Ecuador",
      "idUnidad": 1,
      "idPais": 1,
      "Nombre": "Quito"
    },
    {
      "idEntidad": 1,
      "Pais": "Ecuador",
      "idUnidad": 2,
      "idPais": 1,
      "Nombre": "Guayaquil"
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table" ng-init="mostrarItems()">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">IdPais</th>
          <th scope="col">Pais</th>
          <th scope="col">IdUnidad</th>
          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in List_Data">
          <td ng-bind="item.idPais"></td>
          <td ng-bind="item.Pais"></td>
          <td ng-bind="item.idUnidad"></td>
          <td ng-bind="item.Nombre"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Debe ser en un collapse? No puede ser en un modal por ejemplo?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera el modal es simple, la idea es desplegar debajo del seleccionado

Comment: Es necesario colocar doble idPais al Json?

Comment: bueno, el JSON es resultado de una consulta de dos tablas relacionadas, así que no hay problema si solo esta uno

Comment: Pasa que si quieres mezclar un `table` con un `collapse` no se si puedas lograrlo porque (creo) que vas a tener problemas con elementos que no puedes ir dentro de un table.. Lo que puedes hacer es crear un table dentro de collapses

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera, no quiero usar especificamente collapse, me refiero algo similar, que al presionar aparezca o se deslice

Answer (score 0):

una posible solución podría ser utilizar el elemento `accordion` propio de `Bootstrap` y dentro tener la info que requieras de cada país en una tabla

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    { country: 'Chile', city: 'Santiago', haveCoronavirus: true, openAccordion: true },
    { country: 'Argentina', city: 'Buenos Aires', haveCoronavirus: true, openAccordion: false },
    { country: 'Corea del Norte', city: 'Pionyang', haveCoronavirus: false, openAccordion: false }
  ]  
}])
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <accordion ng-repeat="row in data">
    <accordion-group is-open="row.openAccordion">
      <accordion-heading>
        {{row.country}}
      </accordion-heading>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Ciudad</th>
            <th class="text-center">Tiene coronavirus</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-center" ng-bind="row.city"></td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <i class="fa fa-2x" ng-class="row.haveCoronavirus ? 'fa-check text-success' : 'fa-times text-danger'"></i>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
```

Cabe mencionar que la versión de *Bootstrap que estoy utilizando es la 3.3.7*; si estas usando una versión superior lo más probable es que tengas problemas con `ui.bootstrap` de `AngularJS`, pero no hay problema! **[Acá](https://morgul.github.io/ui-bootstrap4/)** te dejo una versión que te viene increíble si estas utilizando Bootstrap 4, la implementación te la dejo a ti ;).

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas!